# Why was a high wall plug installed in a 1959 home?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

In our 1959 ranch-style home there is an outlet on a living room wall more than halfway up. Anyone know for what use this may have been installed? It looks built-in when the house was built.[image]

Comment: Does a switch control it or does the room have ceiling lights?

Comment: Was it for a radio on a dresser?

Comment: Or was it put above the flood level and the later outlets "forgot"?

Comment: A picture would help.  You can press "Edit" above to edit your question and copy-paste in a JPG.

Comment: Any chance the room used to be a kitchen (or part of one)?  The outlets for refrigerators are also often placed higher up on the wall.

Comment: Probably so, we suspected a clock, but that seems much ado about nothing. But who knows, maybe it was considered that important at the time. I did hang a picture over it. And yes, it is recessed. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: If it was recessed, then yes, it was a clock. In the 1950s-60s, electronic wrist watches weren't technologically possible; you had to wind your watch and you needed something to check its time against. Even today the Electrical Code has a special exception for wall clocks to be on circuits that don't normally allow such loads.

Comment: @Hilldilly sounds like a wall clock outlet to me. In the 50s, alkaline batteries didn't exist, the best they might've had were "heavy duty" zinc chloride batteries -- and the highest-capacity "heavy duty" batteries then pale in comparison to the cheapest alkalines you can get today... so a wall clock would've had an abysmal runtime on an AA battery. Also, 60Hz provides a relatively reliable timing pulse courtesy your local power company, vs. trying to make something that maintains stable timing as battery voltage degrades (now cheap electronics can compensate for this).

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: I need instructions for posting a photo...

Answer (score 32):

Probably for a plug-in electric clock.

Comment: Yep. Some were recessed into the wall so the cord could be hidden. My 1950s home had one in the dining room.

Comment: A good idea in places with a stable power supply... In some places you are better off with a sun dial.

Comment: Our 1950'S home had one in the living room above the fireplace for a clock. the outlet was recessed into the wall

Comment: Our 78 home as one also.  Thing is that even that we did the electric circuits, I have no idea why it was placed there.  The only one in the house.

Comment: The thinking was probably, "if they don't want a clock they can hang a picture over the outlet."

Comment: See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/236119/why-is-there-only-one-receptacle-in-this-outlet

Comment: I guess this is another that depends on where you live. In the UK clock plugs are different to any other plug in the house. Small, maybe 1 1/2" square, recessed.  I can't find a picture as I doubt anyone's installed one since the 50s over here either ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin [UK clock plug & socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets:_British_and_related_types#UK_electric_clock_connector)

Comment: @GrahamNye - that's the one. Well found. I don't think I've seen one in 40 years.

Comment: "hang a picture over the outlet" more than likely, an outlet over the fireplace **is** an outlet for a picture. They would use a t-base tube light in a brass housing on an arm attached to the frame at the top. ( https://www.amazon.com/Picture-light-painting-display-_PCT14/dp/B01921CKIW )

Comment: I'm in Michigan, I don't see the sun from November to March. lol

Answer (score 4):

I would bet it is for a what was called a "pin up" lamp.  A wall lamp with a short cord that was considered stylish and ornamental then. Sometimes placed in pairs, one slightly higher than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Is it near the front door?  It may have been for powering a doorbell.

Is it located near a telephone?  Could have powered an external ringer/clapper unit to alert on incoming phone calls.

But what can it be used for now?  Sounds like an excellent position to put a wireless repeater or access point, or even a low power LED left on all the time as a night light.